# Nearby share how does it handle files with setSensitive = true?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

I am using the [nearby](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/package-summary) API for my Android kotlin application. I use `setSensitive = true` for the files I send. But I am not clear on how this "protected folder" is handled.

In case I am exchanging files and the application crashes, how are these files inside the folder handled if I don't delete them? Are they deleted after a certain period by the Android system? If not, how can I delete them, in case they remain in this folder, before creating a new connection and data exchange?